# .NET - subscribe to a platform event

Tags: platform-event, c#, .net

I would like to subscribe to a platform event. I am trying to create a client in C#/.NET for the Pub/Sub API (gRPC). There are examples in other languages but not in .NET : https://github.com/developerforce/pub-sub-api

I am using the Grpc.Net.Client nuget packages.

```
            var topicName = "/event/SomeEvent__e";
            var pubSubEndpoint = "https://api.pubsub.salesforce.com:7443";
            var accessToken = "xxxx";
            var organisationId = "xxxx";
            var instanceUrl = "https://xxxxx.sandbox.my.salesforce.com";

            var credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((c, m) =>
            {
                m.Add("accesstoken", accessToken);
                m.Add("instanceurl", instanceUrl);
                m.Add("tenantid", organisationId);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            var options = new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials)
            };

            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(pubSubEndpoint, options);
            var client = new PubSub.PubSubClient(channel);

            var topicRequest = new TopicRequest()
            {
                TopicName = topicName
            };
            var topic = client.GetTopic(topicRequest);
```

I know my credentials are correct because I can use postman to hit the oauth2 endpoint and get a valid access token. But when I try and call a client method like client.GetTopic(), then I get the following error.

*Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="An error occurred while getting the metadata for org CORE/prod/00DN0000000c8Hk and topic /event/SomeEvent__e. Ensure the credentials and topic name are correct. rpcId: 21d854fb-17dc-4778-9524-6264bd1a920d")*

Am I setting up the credentials object wrong? I cannot find any example of subscribing to a Salesforce Pub/Sub in .NET.

Comment: gRPC requires you to generate the interface (stubs) based on event definition and then build the client based on the interface.  While there's no .NET example, the Java/Python examples give you a high-level idea of steps you need to perform. gRPC is very new in Salesforce world. As an alternative, you can subscribe via CometD, examples:  [one](https://github.com/kdcllc/CometD.NetCore.Salesforce) [two](https://github.com/Oyatel/CometD.NET).

Comment: Yes I have generated the interface using the proto file.  Like you mentioned, there is the option for the older style of subscribing to the streaming API via CometD.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible and _Complete_ Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.